# Determining the direction of chemical reactions based on the activity series

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox, oxidation-state

> Based on the activity series (table of standard reduction potentials), indicate whether or not the following reactions would occur in the direction written.

Don't worry about what the activity series is, I don't even know what it is so it isn't important. I'm more confused on the procedure and how to find the answer. Would you just find the oxidation states, then find the half reactions according to what the oxidation states are and find the voltage according to the reduction potentials sheet, then be able to tell whether it was spontaneous therefore whether it would run in the direction it was written?

Here are a few of the first questions, the easy ones.

$$\ce{Ag + KNO3 → AgNO3 + K}$$
$$\ce{Zn + AgNO3 → Ag + Zn(NO3)2}$$
$$\ce{Li + H2O → LiOH + H2}$$
$$\ce{Cu + FeSO4 → Fe + CuSO4}$$

Comment: It would be useful to include the reduction potentials with the question. Write out the half reactions, find the potentials and see if their reaction goes in the same direction. If its opposite, flip the sign. When potential has a positive value, its considered favored in that direction.

Comment: Without the value of standard reduction potentials, you cannot answer this question.